# RegEx find word with single digit

Tags: regex

I need to detect words that have special characters @#$ and has less than 2 digits. For example, "ab3c", "a@bc", "a@1c", "4", "a2", etc. While the first part is easy, I am not sure about the second part. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your statement of what you want to match conflicts with your examples. Are you trying to match anything that contains special characters ***and*** has less than two digits, or anything that contains special characters ***or*** has less than two digits?

Comment: It's the latter, the "or" condition - match anything that contains either special characters OR has less than two digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is a bit long, but it works.

```
^[A-Za-z\@\#\$]*\d{0,1}[A-Za-z\@\#\$]*$
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/wlebTZ/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot HK Boy!! There is a slight problem: it does not match "@12" or "@1234", even though it has the special characters. Any help?

Comment: As you said "I need to detect words that have special characters @#$ and **has less than 2 digits**".
If you want to change the condition to `either...or`, just add more 1 regex `^[A-Za-z\@\#\$\d]+$`. Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/A2jw5J/1/).

Answer (score 1):

To match 0 or 1 digit in a string, you can use:

```
^\D*\d?\D*$
```

Comment: Translation: Starting at the beginning of the string, match any number of non-digit characters (including 0), then match 0 or 1 digit, then match any number of non-digit characters (including 0) until the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

If a positive lookahead is supported and you don't want to match empty strings you could use:

```
^(?!(?:[^\d\s]*\d){2})[\w@#$]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead to assert what is directly on the right is not

  - `[^\d\s]*` Match 0+ times not a digit or whitespace char, then match a digit
- `){2}` Close negative lookahead and repeat 2 times because if that succeeds the assertion will not pass
- `[\w@#$]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed in the character class
- `$` End of string

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/k0XRW5/1)

If you have multiple words, you change ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/k0XRW5/2)) the anchors `^` and `$` to word boundaries `\b`